# Open device explorer and add files from device

Tags: android

I want to select files from device explorer and add selected files to android `GridView`.

I have tried below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String Fpath = data.getDataString();
    Log.d("stringpaths", Fpath);

}
```

Comment: Good try, what is your problem with this ?where your are adding files to gridview ?

Comment: select files from device and add selected files to girdview.

Comment: where you are adding files to grid /

Comment: In my gridview activity I have a custom dialog on cliclk of add files from device ,I should be able to add files to gridview.